# How do I take an input and make the program print out each letter on a new line while making every space encounter to print out "<space>"?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TwoDotSevenNumbaTwo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String input;
        int num1, num2, leng;
        char word;
        Scanner inputscan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Give me some love baby");
        input = inputscan.nextLine();
        leng = input.length();
        num1 = 0;
        num2 = 1;

        while (num1 < leng) {
            input = input.replaceAll(" ", "<space>");
            System.out.println(input.charAt(num1));

            num1++;
        }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the `<space>` on a single line. I know I can't do it because it is a char but I can't find a way around it.

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
for(int i = 0; i < leng; ++i) {
   char x = input.charAt(i);
   System.out.println(x == ' ' ? "<space>" : x);
}
```

Comment: `num1+="<space>".length();` this line is wrong. You read a space, so it's only 1 char. The `num1++` go after the conditional.

Answer (score 1):

Once you've stored the input as a String, you can write:

```
// Break the string into individual chars
for (char c: input.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == ' ') { // If the char is a space...
        System.out.println("<space>");
    }
    else { // Otherwise...
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex powa:

```
yourText.replaceAll(".", "$0\n").replaceAll(" ","<space>");
```

Explanation:

First replaceAll takes every charachter (`.` = any character) and replaces it with the same character (`$0` = matched text) followed by a newline `\n`, thusly every character is on separate line.

Second replaceAll just replaces every acctual space with the word `"<space>"`

For java regex tutorial, you can follow [this link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) or use your favourite search engine to find plenty more.

Comment: Could you better word/elaborate on your answer?